# How to Update Listview subitem in C# Windows Application P-SQL(MS Access-oledb connection c#)

Tags: c#, sql, listview, ms-access

I am trying to write a program that includes datacollection system based on database(Ms access) in c# windows form application.

The application consist of;

*Textboxes
*Listview
*Buttons
*ms access oledb database connection

[Program Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6EiW.jpg)

Everythng is working well except update function which is used as button.

In this case(update function button)Firstly, I would like to fill the textboxes with new datas like ıd number and so on..., Then selecting the row that I want to change and click update button to change whole row with entered datas which is avaliable in textboxes.But I couldn't make it.

Basically ı would like to change the row of listview(database) with new datas which is avaliable in text boxes.

I add delete function codes here which allows me to delete a selected row in listview and database.It is working well.I would like to make this update function button in a same way of delete function button

**Delete function button(working well and delete selected row in database and Listview):**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();//open database
        //delete command
        OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE IDNumber=@IDNumber", connection);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNumber", listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();//Girmiş olduğumuz parametreyi geri gönderir
        connection.Close();
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        showdatas();  
    }
```

**Update button codes that ı want it to run same way as delete function button(It should update selected row with new datas in textboxes):**

This code is not working as ı mentioned above:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //you can change selected things in the list(update button)
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand ab = new OleDbCommand("insert into Table1 WHERE IDNumber=@IDNumber (ProductNumber,ProductDeveloperName,ProductDeveloperSurname,ProductDeveloperID,ProductDeveloperAge,ProductCost) values ('" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox6.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox7.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox2.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox5.Text.ToString() + "' )", connection);
        ab.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNumber", listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
        ab.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        showdatas();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is wrong.  You should put your column names near from your table name.

```
insert into Table1(ProductNumber,ProductDeveloperName,ProductDeveloperSurname,ProductDeveloperID,ProductDeveloperAge,ProductCost)...
```

You can't use `WHERE` with `INSERT` statement. It does not *even* exist in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

A few things more;

- You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.
- Do not use `AddWithValue`. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

By the way, based on their names, your `ProductNumber`, `ProductDeveloperID`, `ProductDeveloperAge`, `ProductCost` should be numerical typed columns, not chacacters. Check your column types twice. Don't have a [bad habit as choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Comment: 1)I couldn't understand how to implement this use function into my codes.    2)Before learning paremeterized queries, I would like to make this update function work  3) I have changed Sql code like :"insert into Table1 (ProductNumber,ProductDeveloperName,ProductDeveloperSurname,ProductDeveloperID,ProductDeveloperAge,ProductCost) values ('" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox6.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox7.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox2.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox5.Text.ToString() + "' )", connection);

Comment: 5)They are all string type, I am not going to make any additional mathematical calculation. 6)Could you please help me to make this update button work? 7)I will be really appreciated